# split list selections into DIVs to show when selected

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have code that selects items from a database and when selected displays corresponding items in another listbox, but i want the first one to show initally and then show the second one in a diferent div when an item selected from the first one. So its the one after the 'select vehicle' that i want to show when 'Select type of vehicle' is selected. Having problems splitting them apart as it is so any help would be great.

the code is :

```
    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="input-group">
 Select type of vehicle : <select name=category id=category>
<option value='' selected>Please select</option>
<?Php
require "config.php";// connection to database 
$sql="select * from category "; // Query to collect data 

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo "<option name=vehicle_type value=$row[cat_id]>$row[category]</option>";
}
?>
</div>

<div style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><br></span></div>

<div><div style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="input-group">
</select>
Select vehicle : <select name=vehicle_id id=sub-category></select>

</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code is not clear. Can you please re-check it again (I think you have some issues with tages opening and closing)? And please indent it so it look clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this. I moved your first select's closing tag out of the other select's div, added the class **hide** and the id **select-vehicle**.

HTML:

```
</select>
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px" class="input-group hide" id="select-vehicle">
    Select vehicle : <select name=vehicle_id id=sub-category></select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#category" ).change(function() {
    if ($(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') == ''){
        // User removed type of vehicle. Hide the vehicle selection
        $( "#select-vehicle" ).addClass( "hide" );
    } else {
        // User chose type vehicle. Show the vehicle selection
        $( "#select-vehicle" ).removeClass( "hide" );
    }
});
```

Edit:

Comment: HI, it works good thanks, but how do you hids the div if they deselect an item?

Comment: @Jules Great! I've edited the post above to re-hide it if they deselect.